# Keycloak cannot propagate user-group mappings from LDAP into user-group mappings

Tags: ldap, keycloak

I am trying to setup User Federation from a LDAP server to Keycloak. I managed to import all the users and groups respectively from LDAP server, however, the user-group (group tab in Users section) doesn’t show the actual mapped groups, although I can see those users presenting in the groups listed in Members tab in Groups section…

I went through all article in Keycloak forum/Jira ticket/Mail list and I did find a ticket describing the exact issue that I am experiencing now  (https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2018-February/013076.html) and Marek has also replied to that as well, however, I still couldn't figure out what configuration I set incorrectly just by the information provided in the post.

Could anyone please help me out? Thanks ahead!

[User-Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUpPQ.png)

[Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UIXO.png)

[User Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wykdY.png)

[Group Mapper Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0GwG.png)

Thanks,

Chance

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue was in LDAP server. The problem only exists when I import the users from FreeIPA DB. However, when I try to federate to an AD server, the user-group information just comes along with the users without any additional modification!

Below is the configuration I have used in the successful case. Hopefully it will help others who encounter with a similar issue. Thanks everyone for the attention.

```
[User Federation Provider Settings]
Enabled: ON (Default)
Console Display Name : <Name whatever you like>
Priority: 0 (Default)
Import Users : ON (Default)
Edit Mode : READ_ONLY 
Sync Registrations : OFF (Default)
Vendor : Active Directory  (This is important. Once I switch to AD, instead of FreeIPA, the issue is gone)
Username LDAP attribute: sAMAccountName
RDN LDAP attribute : cn
UUID LDAP attribute : objectGUID
User Object Classes : person, organizationalPerson, user   (You should check what Object Class the server is currently configured and adjust accordingly)
Connection URL :  ldap://<your LDAP server domain name>:389  (If you are using ldaps, the port is 636)
Users DN : <the scope includes all your users you would like to import, e.g. OU=User,DC=example,DC=com)
Bind Type: simple
Enable StartTLS: OFF (Default)
Bind DN: <The account has permission to search within LDAP tree>
Bind Credential: <The password for above account>
Custom User LDAP Filter: <You can leave it blank if you don't want to filter. However, if you would like to filter something, for example, users from a specific group, you can run a filter such as (&(objectClass=user)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=<groupName>,OU=<groupOU>,DC=example,DC=com))    >
Search Scope: Subtree  (It the users after under one level of Users DN, you can choose "One level" option)
Validate Password Policy: OFF (Default)
Trust Email: OFF (Default)
Use Truststore SPI: Only for ldaps
Connection Pooling: On
```

The rest of setting leave it blank.

You need to configure a group-ldap-mapper as well

```
[Group Mapper]
Name: <Whatever name you like>
Mapper Type: group-ldap-mapper
LDAP Groups DN : <Where are the groups of this tree saved. For example, OU=Group,DC=example,DC=com>
Group Name LDAP Attribute : cn
Group Object Classes : group
Preserve Group Inheritance: ON
Ignore Missing Groups: OFF (Default)
Membership LDAP Attribute : member
Membership Attribute Type: DN
Membership User LDAP Attribute: sAMAccountName
LDAP Filter : <You can leave it blank if you don't want to filter any group>
Mode: READ_ONLY
User Groups Retrieve Strategy: LOAD_GROUPS_BY_MEMBER_ATTRIBUTE
Member-Of LDAP Attribute: memberOf
Mapped Group Attributes: <You can leave it blank>
Drop non-existing groups during sync: ON
```